# Can you install Ubuntu to another partition from Windows?

Tags: system-installation, windows, wubi

I have a dual boot PC whose Ubuntu installation is broken. Moreover due to a problem with BIOS I'm not able to boot from USB. I wonder if I can reinstall Ubuntu using a Windows program. I think this should be possible because Grub is already installed in the boot loader. However Wubi does not seem to do such a thing.

Comment: Sudodus has made some Ubuntu images that can be flashed to a HDD partition, once flashed, the GRUB menuentry can be coppied to your existing grub.cfg file. https://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/uefi-n-bios/dd_unb_ubuntu-20.04_15GB_2020-09-07_with-proposed.img.xz (It is 1.5GB to download and expands to 15GB once flashed). I am not sure of the best way to flash the .img image file without booting from USB.

Answer (score 0):

### UNetbootin Frugal Installer

You can make a Frugal install of Ubuntu to your hard drive that can be used to make a Full install to it.

Full details are given on this page:

https://github.com/unetbootin/unetbootin/wiki/installmodes

See: **Making a full, standard hard disk install if you can't use a Live USB** on that page.

I think it is working with UNetbootin Windows 681, but not sure if it works with GRUB.

If you try it please let us know your results.

Comment: It doesn't give me any options for choosing the partition.

Comment: UNetbootin just puts a temporary Frugal install on the hard drive. The next time you boot you can start a Live session and do a Full install, as if you had just booted from Live USB. ie instead of putting the installer on a USB it puts the installer on a piece of the hard drive.